# selectionChanged() of IActionDelegate in not getting invoked

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an action class which I would like to enable depending on the file extension.
I have written this logic in the `selectionChanged()` of the action class.

But when I start my eclipse, and click on the file for the context menu, this method is not getting called.
And when I click on any action, there after any click on the file invokes the `selectionChanged()` method.

How can I make the `selectionChanged()` method to be called always on click of files in eclipse in order to disable the actions before clicking on the action?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of actions enabled/disabled based on the type of element currently selected.
See for instance the "Copy" actions on an element not meant to be copied:

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20120503153234/http://img522.i_mageshack.us/img522/448/eclipseinactivecommand.png]

That means you can check how a [**`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart`**](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/packageview/PackageExplorerPart.java.htm) manages its own contextual menu and their associated actions.

Start from the method [`menuAboutToShow()`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/packageview/PackageExplorerPart.java.htm#ixzz0ft30B0b3), using a [`PackageExplorerActionGroup`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/packageview/PackageExplorerActionGroup.java.htm) class, including a [`CCPActionGroup`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/actions/CCPActionGroup.java.htm) which manage to Copy, Cut and Paste actions.
That last class illistrates the registration of Actions, amongst them the [`CopyToClipboardAction`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/refactoring/reorg/CopyToClipboardAction.java.htm):
It does implement a [`selectionChanged` method](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/refactoring/reorg/CopyToClipboardAction.java.htm#ixzz0ft4rU7E6).

```
public void selectionChanged(IStructuredSelection  selection) {
 try {
   List JavaDoc elements= selection.toList();
   IResource[] resources= ReorgUtils.getResources(elements);
   IJavaElement[] javaElements= ReorgUtils.getJavaElements(elements);
   if (elements.size() != resources.length + javaElements.length)
    setEnabled(false);
      else
    setEnabled(canEnable(resources, javaElements));
  } catch (JavaModelException e) {
   //no ui here - this happens on selection changes
   // http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19253
   if (JavaModelUtil.isExceptionToBeLogged(e))
     JavaPlugin.log(e);
   setEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: But problem is that selectionChanged is getting invoked only after the action is performed. Is there a way to load the action when plugin is loaded.
In my case only after clicking on the action that is when IActionDelegate is loaded, I am able to enable/disable the action.

Comment: @reek: Not sure; the initial selection is more likeky to be set each time the selection change because it is based upon the nature of the selected element.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are "suffering" from Eclipse's lazy plugin loading (just like me). You can check the Eclipse Plugin-book, or the [manual for popups](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_popupMenus.html) (which I assume you are using). You have to use the so-called declarative mechanism for enabling your item. In your case, it should be as simple as just adding a `nameFilter`. That way, Eclipse can avoid loading your plugin until it actually needs to run (decoupling of menu items and plugin execution).