# Eclipse Plugin: Enablement of an Action based on the current selection

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am using the org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus extension point for adding a sub-menu whose Action that is bounded to the following class:

```
  public class MyAction implements IObjectActionDelegate {

     private Logic logic = Logic.getInstance(); // Singleton

     public void setActivePart(IAction a, IWorkbenchPart targetPart) {
        // Nothing here
     }

     public void run(IAction a) {      
        // Do something...
     }

     public void selectionChanged(IAction a, ISelection s) {
        a.setEnabled(logic.isEnabled(s));
     }
  }
```

This action is working correctly in most cases (including the call `a.setEnabled()` in `selectionChanged()`).
My problem at the very first time my action is being invoked. The `selectionChanged` method is called only *after* the menu item has been displayed (and not when the user has made the selection) which means that the call to `a.setEnabled()` will have no affect.

Any ideas on how to make my action receive `selectionChanged()` notifications even before the fist time it is being invoked?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses so-called lazy plugin activation, so it first derives as much as possible from plugin.xml, and the behaviour you are observing is well-documented in the API. [See this related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287644/selectionchanged-of-iactiondelegate-in-not-getting-invoked/3235733#3235733)

Answer (score 0):

The words *first time* and *after* make me wonder about a synchronization problem. If the initialization of `Logic.getInstance()` is deferred, you might look at the [*Initialization On Demand Holder Idiom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom), also discussed in item 71 of [*Effective Java*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/).

Comment: No, it's related to Eclipse's way of handling plugins. Fortunately no synchronization involved!